# html file src path errror and 404 not found

Tags: html, vue.js, pdf, vue-cli

I want to view img or pdf document my webpage.But I cant show **img** or **pdf** because of path writing.

I have a directory and it has a vue file, pdf and img.I want to run this files my `vue.js` file but it give me *`error 404 not found`*.Its weird.

Same directory but it run :

```
localhost:8080/deneme.jpg
```

But I want

```
path='localhost:8080:/#/src/assets/DemoPages/Hasta/deneme.jpg'
```

Whats wrong?

```
<div class="widget-content-left mr-3">
     <img src="deneme.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: improved formatting

Comment: If the `.jpg` file is in the same folder as the `.vue` file, you can use `src="./deneme.jpg"`.

Comment: thank you.It worked img but pdf is still cant found

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `/` in front of your asset src. It should solve the problem. Adding a `/` will make it look at the absolute path instead of the relative path.

Code:

```
div class="widget-content-left mr-3">
     <img src="/deneme.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `require`

```
<img :src="require('deneme.jpg')"> // deneme.jpg is path from this file to image
```